# Терминал открывается каждый раз после компиляции SCSS

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы терминал не открывался при каждом изменении в scss коде?

То есть, я буквально ставлю пробел в коде или делаю любое другое изменение кода и тут же выскакивает терминал.[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь настройкой `liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindowOn`, например можно выставить "error" и будет открываться только при ошибках.